# Can a novelty detection model overfit?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, unsupervised-learning, overfitting, outlier

**Can a novelty detection model overfit?** In novelty detection, the model is trained on normal data instances (not polluted by outliers) where no labels are used in the training process, while validated and tested on a data instances that contain outliers in them. An example of algorithms that can be used for novelty detection are one-class SVM (OCSVM) and Local Outlier Factor (LOF).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering your question: yes, depending on the hyperparameters you choose, you could overfit the considered normal data, if you fit your separating hyperplane between normal and novel points being too much "shaped" on your input data.
There are, for instance in case of one-class support vector machines, some important hyperparams like nu or gamma:

- ***nu***: with this one, you tell the oc-SVM the fraction of novel points (i.e. anomalies) you want to consider in your input data; this way, you don't overfit your model by not considering normal all the input data (it also depends on your use case, how sure you want to be about normality of the input data points...)
  You can test it with the scikit-learn package this way:

***with nu=0.01***
[image]

VS ***with nu=0.1***, where you tell the model to consider a higher fraction of points as being abnormal:

[image]

so, the lower nu value is, the more you are "overfitting" your novelties detector (which could be better or worse depending on how well you know your input data).

- ***gamma***: now, look at the effect of the value of gamma, which is crucial for overfitting your model:

with gamma=0.1 (and rbf kernel), you have the following decision surface:
[image]

VS with gamma = 10

[image]

where, with this last option, your are overfitting so much.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I thought the higher gamma value, the better as the model would be able to separate normal data from outliers (as shown in the given examples). If I am tuning the model hyperparameters, I will definitely go through a combination of the values you just provided in the examples, so probably I will overfit my model. Based on the scenario I provided, what is the best way to avoid overfitting?

Comment: the point here is that, as semi-supervised learning (sub-type os unsupervised), you cannot validate "as well" as with labels/values in supervised learning, so you must find a good balance as you beging having more "normal" data, so there is no a best rule in advance but a balance to look for

Comment: I have one last question if you don't mind. How can I tell that I am overfitting? Is it the same as supervised learning? When the test results are less than than the validation results (let's say f_score results or roc auc score results)?

Comment: I would check whether new considered normal data points are labeled as novelties or not, by using the so called anomaly score, which gives you a sense of how far these fall from the separating hyperplane; in a real use case I made in automotive industry, this was not easy to consider, as the experts were not sure about the normal conditions (so I wasn't either then) but i used an anomaly score to check if new points candidates of being "normal" were too far apart or not (by studying these scores distribution). BTW, please check the answer as valid (green tick) if you consider it valid :)

Comment: I am a bit lost now. Do you mean to compare the anomaly score of each data instances in the validation set with the average anomaly score of the training set and see how far the points from the average? If they are far from each other then I am overfitting my model, is that right?

Comment: that seems to me a valid aproximation, but adding some criteria: for instance, check how many standard deviations is the score of a normal instance in the validation set from the mean score of the training set scores distribution. What I did in that real use case is to only consider as novel points the ones falling 2*sigma far from the mean score (because my model could send too many false positives by the nature of the system), but that can be different in your case, just experiment with it and validate if you can so you can adjust it

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. One of my objectives is to reduce false positives rates. To summarize train the model, and evaluate on the validation set by tuning the hyperparameters, compare the training and validation anomaly score based on criteria. If the normal data instance in the validation set falls within the defined criteria then the model is indeed working very well and able to differentiate between inliers and outliers. I hope I got it right

Comment: that sounds a reasonable approach to me, but remember, you do not have that "working very well" certainty as in supervised learning, so you should rely on experience and real feedback to confirm it :)